# React- onSubmit Function on forms is not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to console log when i click on a button on a form element using onSubmit function.

```
export class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ''
  };

  onFormSubmit = e => {
    console.log('Working');
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className='form' />
        <input
          type='text'
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.text}
          name='text'
          placeholder='Search Users...'
        />
        <input
          type='submit'
          value='Search'
          className='btn btn-dark btn-block'
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrapping your button in `form` but closing the `form` itself,

```
 <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className='form' />
```

You need to wrap `input` and `button` in `form` like,

```
<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className='form'>
   <input
       type='text'
       onChange={this.onChange}
       value={this.state.text}
       name='text'
       placeholder='Search Users...'
   />
   <input
      type='submit'
      value='Search'
      className='btn btn-dark btn-block'
   />
</form> //form closing tag
```

Comment: Lol. I was using prettier it automatically formatted it to self closing tag and i didn't realise it. btw thanks again.